# Trying to import the tailwind config to access color values as js vars in a .tsx file throws an error (using vite with react-swc plugin as build tool)

Tags: javascript, typescript, tailwind-css, vite, commonjs

I have a problem trying to import my defined values from tailwind.config.cjs into PageStats.tsx. Could someone provide me with a clear answer to what I am doing wrong?

This is the file trying to import it:

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "../components/Card";
import resolveConfig from "tailwindcss/resolveConfig";
import tailwindConfig from "../../tailwind.config.cjs";

type Props = {};
const mockData = [
...
];

const cssConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig);
let accent = "#8884d8";
if (cssConfig && cssConfig.theme && cssConfig.theme.colors) {
accent = cssConfig?.theme?.color['accent'];
};

function PageStats({}: Props) {
  return (
  [...]
  );
}

export default PageStats;
```

This is my tailwind.config.cjs:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./public/*.svg"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        gradient: {
          '0%, 100%': { 'background-size': '400% 400%', 'background-position': '0% 50%' },
          '50%': { 'background-size': '200% 200%', 'background-position': '100% 50%' },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        gradient: 'gradient 7s ease infinite',
      },
      boxShadow: {
        'outline': '0 0 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
      },
      colors: {
        'primary': '#0F172A',
        'secondary': '#181E41',
        'tertiary': '#2C2F54',
        'pop': '#FFCDB2',
        'pop-2': '#ff9090',
        'accent': '#574AE2',
        'success': '#2F9C95',
        'warning': '#F2CD5D',
        'danger': '#FF1053',
        'info': '#4465FF', 
      },
      borderRadius: {
        'ce': '12px'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: []
};
```

There is no error in my IDE (VSCode), only these errors in my browser:
[image]

Maybe it has something to do with Vite, however I am really clueless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vite does not support commonJS out of box. Now since `tailwind.config.cjs` is commonJS you need some config to get it to work:

```js
import commonjs from 'vite-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  plugins: [commonjs()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.mts', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json', '.cjs']
  }
}
```

You need `vite-plugin-commonjs` which transpile commonJS into JS module file.

You also need to add `'.cjs'` to `resolve.extensions` list. Otherwise above plugin won't work either. (This is because the default list of vite is `['.mjs', '.js', '.mts', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.json']` [source](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/c3f6731bafeadd310efa4325cb8dcc639636fe48/packages/vite/src/node/constants.ts#L25-L33)). I stuck here for a while.